# Definitions for CRL Reasons

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, x.509, crl

Is there any authoritative definition of the various reasons possible in a CRL file? [Section 6.3.2(b) of RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6.3.2) lists a few:

- unspecified
- keyCompromise
- cACompromise
- affiliationChanged
- superseded
- cessationOfOperation
- certificateHold
- removeFromCRL
- privilegeWithdrawn
- aACompromise

I've looked and looked and can't find any reputable explanation of what these statuses each technically mean and I don't want to just assume their meaning given how the reason is phrased.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*[Disclaimer: I work as a software developer on the software that powers one of the trusted public CAs, and many corporate internal PKIs]*

**tl;dr: to my knowledge, there are no formal guidelines for which revocation reason should be used in which situation, it's up to the discretion of the administrator or operator of each CA.**

Typically, cert revocations are done by humans who have to choose one of those revocation reasons from a drop-down menu in the GUI. That means deciding which bucket a certain edge-case falls into may vary from one organization / CA to another, or may be entirely up to the discretion of the IT guy who is revoking the certificate for your ID badge, email access, web server, wtv.

### In corporate Windows Active Directory CAs:

I found [a really old article by Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc700843.aspx) giving a bit of a text description of each reason -- search for "Revocation Reasons" on the page. (Microsoft built CA software as part of the Active Directory suite, so I assume this is accompanying documentation intended for Windows Domain Admins). See Appendix A at the bottom for the full list.

### In the public internet TLS PKI

The CA/Browser Forum (CAB Forum) dictates policy for how publicly-trusted CAs and browsers need to behave with respect to certificates. Here is the [CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements for the Issuance and Management of Publicly-Trusted Certificates, v.1.2.5, April 2015](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/BRv1.2.5.pdf). If you go to section *13.1.5 Reasons for Revoking a Subscriber Certificate* (see Appendix B below), there is a list of situations in which the CA is required to revoke a certificate, but no mention of which reason code they're supposed to use.

**tl;dr again: to my knowledge, there are no formal guidelines for which revocation reason should be used in which situation, it's up to the discretion of the administrator or operator of each CA.**

---

Appendix A: [some guidance from Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc700843.aspx) on when to use each revocation reason:

> - KeyCompromise. The token or disk location where the private key associated with the certificate has been compromised and is in the possession of an unauthorized individual. This can include the case where a laptop is stolen, or a smart card is lost.
> - CACompromise. The token or disk location where the CA's private key is stored has been compromised and is in the possession of an unauthorized individual. When a CA's private key is revoked, this results in all certificates issued by the CA that are signed using the private key associated with the revoked certificate being considered revoked.
> - AffiliationChanged. The user has terminated his or her relationship with the organization indicated in the Distinguished Name attribute of the certificate. This revocation code is typically used when an individual is terminated or has resigned from an organization. You do not have to revoke a certificate when a user changes departments, unless your security policy requires different certificate be issued by a departmental CA.
> - Superseded. A replacement certificate has been issued to a user, and the reason does not fall under the previous reasons. This revocation reason is typically used when a smart card fails, the password for a token is forgotten by a user, or the user has changed their legal name.
> - CessationOfOperation. If a CA is decommissioned, no longer to be used, the CA's certificate should be revoked with this reason code. Do not revoke the CA's certificate if the CA no longer issues new certificates, yet still publishes CRLs for the currently issued certificates.
> - CertificateHold. A temporary revocation that indicates that a CA will not vouch for a certificate at a specific point in time. Once a certificate is revoked with a CertificateHold reason code, the certificate can then be revoked with another Reason Code, or unrevoked and returned to use.
>
>   Note: While CertificateHold allows a certificate to be "unrevoked", it is not recommended to place a hold on a certificate, as it becomes difficult to determine if a certificate was valid for a specific time.
> - RemoveFromCRL. If a certificate is revoked with the CertificateHold reason code, it is possible to "unrevoke" a certificate. The unrevoking process still lists the certificate in the CRL, but with the reason code set to RemoveFromCRL.
>
>   Note: This is specific to the CertificateHold reason and is only used in DeltaCRLs.
> - Unspecified. It is possible to revoke a certificate without providing a specific reason code. While it is possible to revoke a certificate with the Unspecified reason code, this is not recommended, as it does not provide an audit trail as to why a certificate is revoked.

---

Appendix B: *13.1.5 Reasons for Revoking a Subscriber Certificate* from [CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements for the Issuance and Management of Publicly-Trusted Certificates, v.1.2.5, April 2015](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/BRv1.2.5.pdf):

> [CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements for the Issuance and Management of Publicly-Trusted Certificates, v.1.2.5, April 2015](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/BRv1.2.5.pdf)[CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements for the Issuance and Management of Publicly-Trusted Certificates, v.1.2.5, April 2015](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/BRv1.2.5.pdf):
>
> 1. The Subscriber requests in writing that the CA revoke the Certificate;
> 2. The  Subscriber  notifies  the  CA  that  the  original  certificate  request  was  not  authorized  and  does  not retroactively grant authorization;
> 3. The  CA  obtains  evidence  that  the  Subscriber’s  Private  Key  corresponding  to  the  Public  Key  in  the Certificate  suffered  a  Key  Compromise  (also  see  Section  10.2.4) or no longer complies with the requirements of Appendix A;
> 4. The CA obtains evidence that the Certificate was misused;
> 5. The CA is made aware that a Subscriber has violated one or more of its material obligations under the Subscriber or Terms of Use Agreement;
> 6. The CA is made aware of any circumstance indicating that use of a Fully-Qualified Domain Name or IP address in the Certificate is no longer legally permitted (e.g. a court or arbitrator has revoked a Domain 
>      Name Registrant’s right to use the Domain Name, a relevant licensing or services agreement between the Domain Name Registrant and the Applicant has terminated, or the Domain Name Registrant has failed to renew the Domain Name);
> 7. The CA is made aware that a Wildcard Certificate has been used to authenticate a fraudulently misleading subordinate Fully-Qualified Domain Name;
> 8. The CA is made aware of a material change in the information contained in the Certificate;
> 9. The CA is made aware that the Certificate was not issued in accordance with these Requirements or the CA’s Certificate Policy or Certification Practice Statement;
> 10. The CA determines that any of the information appearing in the Certificate is inaccurate or misleading;
> 11. The  CA  ceases  operations  for  any  reason  and  has  not  made  arrangements  for  another  CA  to  provide revocation support for the Certificate;
> 12. The CA’s right to issue Certificates under these Requirements expires or is revoked or terminated, unless the CA has made arrangements to continue maintaining the CRL/OCSP Repository;
> 13. The CA is made aware of a possible compromise of the Private Key of the Subordinate CA used for issuing the Certificate;
> 14. Revocation is required by the CA’s Certificate Policy and/or Certification Practice Statement; or
> 15. The technical content or format of the Certificate presents an unacceptable risk to Application Software Suppliers  or  Relying  Parties  (e.g.  the  CA/Browser  Forum  might  determine  that  a  deprecated cryptographic/signature  algorithm  or  key  size  presents  an  unacceptable  risk  and  that  such  Certificates should be revoked and replaced by CAs within a given period of time).

Comment: Thank you. This is so informative, and exactly what I was looking for today. This information is amazingly difficult to find. You'd think that the definitions of the reason codes would be supplied in the RFC.

Answer (score 8):

In [ITU-T-X.509-201210](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.509-201210-S!!PDF-E&type=items) they are explained in section 8.5.3.1 (Reason code extension) as:

> – **unspecified** can be used to revoke certificates for reasons other than the specific codes.
>
> – **keyCompromise** is used in revoking an end-entity certificate; it indicates that it is known or suspected
>   that the subject's private key, or other aspects of the subject validated in the certificate, have been
>   compromised.
>
> – **cACompromise** is used in revoking a CA-certificate; it indicates that it is known or suspected that the
>   subject's private key, or other aspects of the subject validated in the certificate, have been compromised.
>
> – **affiliationChanged** indicates that the subject's name or other information in the certificate has been modified but there is no cause to suspect that the private key has been compromised.
>
> – **superseded** indicates that the certificate has been superseded but there is no cause to suspect that the private key has been compromised.
>
> – **cessationOfOperation** indicates that the certificate is no longer needed for the purpose for which it was issued but there is no cause to suspect that the private key has been compromised.
>
> – **privilegeWithdrawn** indicates that a certificate (public-key or attribute certificate) was revoked because a privilege contained within that certificate has been withdrawn.
>
> – **aACompromise** indicates that it is known or suspected that aspects of the AA validated in the attribute certificate have been compromised.

And they also explain hold and remove; but hold just means "temporarily revoked" and "remove" is placed on delta-CRLs to say "uh, that hold was cancelled". Per X.509 the subsequent "full" CRL simply won't list the certificate any longer.

It's also noteworthy that technically this extension is entirely optional.  Both RFCs 3280 and 5280 say that a conforming CA "SHOULD" provide the reason code.  X.509 has very little to say about when to use it, just what it means if it was used.

Comment: Thank you. I needed this information today.